# How to get a single value from FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am aware that I can get the values of a form using

```
JSON.stringify(this.formName.value)
```

However, I want to get a single value from the form.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can get value like this

```
this.form.controls['your form control name'].value
```

Comment: `this.form.controls.email.value` also works without the brackets, but its up to you which style you prefer

Comment: As said by @Julia, getting value by the "get()" method is better than this.

Answer (score 195):

Yes, you can.

```
this.formGroup.get('name of you control').value
```

Comment: This should be right answer since you access via method rather than getting controls directly

Comment: Of course, this is the method used in the official documentation too. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I want this to work - but depending on where you're using it in a component life cycle it may throw an error regarding `get()` not being available on the form. Where as using the `this.form.value.{name}` will properly return the value.

Answer (score 40):

Dot notation will break the type checking, switch to bracket notation. You might also try using the get() method. It also keeps AOT compilation in tact I've read.

```
this.form.get('controlName').value // safer
this.form.controlName.value // triggers type checking and breaks AOT
```

Comment: I concur with the `.get()` method, however need to end with `.value` I think: `this.form.get('controlName').value`

Comment: I appreciate this answer as it gives the WHY.  Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

**for Angular 6+ and >=RC.6**

```
.html

<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input type="text" formControlName="myName">
</form>

.ts

public formGroup: FormGroup;
this.formGroup.value.myName
```

should also work.

Comment: the same , it's the most intuitive

Answer (score 13):

Another option:

```
this.form.value['nameOfControl']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getRawValue()`

```
this.formGroup.getRawValue().attribute
```

Answer (score 3):

This code also works:

```
this.formGroup.controls.nameOfcontrol.value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by the following ways

```
this.your_form.getRawValue()['formcontrolname]
this.your_form.value['formcontrolname]
```