# how to pass a value from a field in angular using form?

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

When a button is clicked I wanted to pass the value of the input field which has the formControlName email to the function , can someone give me an idea or help ? thank.

#html code

```
<div>
                    <div fxLayout="column">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="" autocomplete="email" formControlName="email">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
                                Username is required.
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <button (click)="getStarted()" mat-flat-button color="primary"
                            type="submit" class="v-btn-sml" id="get-started-button">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

#.ts

```
  getStarted() {
    // I want to pass the input value from the username field here when button is clicked
  }

  private Form(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.model.id || 0],
      email: new FormControl(this.model.email, [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hello Art. Would this be sufficient to answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713558/how-to-get-a-single-value-from-formgroup

Comment: would appreciate Sir if you could provide an example based on my example . thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have defined `modelForm` as a property on your component,

```
getStarted(){
    const value = this.modelForm.value['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

u can achieve it this way:

```
getStarted() {
   const inputValue = this.modelForm.get('email').value
  }
```