# How to bind a form made using FormRecord (Angular 14) to the HTML <form>?

Tags: typescript, angular-forms, formgroups, angular14

Angular 14 has released the Typed Forms concept. I am trying to use that in place of a FormGroup. ALl okay in the ts, but in HTML, how shall we bind it to the HTML  tag, like we used to do for FormGroup?

For formgroup we did
`<form [formGroup]="myForm">`
It seems there no such option for FormRecord. Please can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property binding techniques like `<form [formGroup]="myForm">` should still work with `FormRecord` because `FormRecord` extends `FormGroup`.

---

From the documentation on [FormRecord](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormRecord), it can be seen that it extends [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).

```
class FormRecord<TControl extends AbstractControl<ɵValue<TControl>, ɵRawValue<TControl>> = AbstractControl, TControl> extends FormGroup<{
    [key: string]: TControl;
}>
```

In general, any technique that's applicable to `FormGroup` will work with `FormRecord` as well, like [getting a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43713692/13172506):

`this.formGroup.get('name of you control').value`

Here's a simple somewhat dynamic StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v14-playground-c1ak5m?embed=1&file=src/main.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public myForm: FormRecord;
  public formKeys = ['Andrew', 'Barry']

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = new FormRecord<FormControl<string|null>>({});
    this.formKeys.forEach((key, i) => 
      this.myForm.addControl(key, new FormControl(`${(i + 1) * 100} Default-Value St.`))
    );

  }
```

```
    <div>
      <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <div *ngFor="let key of formKeys">
          <b>{{key}}: </b><input  [formControlName]="key"><br/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
    <br/>
    <div *ngFor="let key of formKeys">
      <div>{{key}}: {{myForm.get(key).value}}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```